# How to get the call details from Twilio Voice Javascript SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I just started to build a browser to browser call by following the code and steps at [here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-csharp). It is a Twilio Javascript Voice SDK quickstart.

However, I am having hard time to find the call details after the call. I want to retrieve the call log of my client but I could find any call data at the TwiMl App I've configured.
I am expecting each time I ended the call, I can retrieve the call data such as to,from,recording,length and etc...

I've came across several approach :

```
 async function makeOutgoingCall() {
        var params = {
            To: phoneNumberInput.value,
            callingDeviceIdentity
        };

        if (device) {
            log(`Attempting to call ${params.To} ... `);

            // Twilio.Device.connect() returns a Call object
            const call = await device.connect({ params });
            console.log(call);
            // add listeners to the Call
            // "accepted" means the call has finished connecting and the state is now "open"
            call.on("accept", updateUIAcceptedOutgoingCall);
            call.on("disconnect", updateUIDisconnectedOutgoingCall);
            call.on("cancel", updateUIDisconnectedOutgoingCall);

            outgoingCallHangupButton.onclick = () => {
                log("Hanging up ...");
                call.disconnect();
            };

        } else {
            log("Unable to make call.");
        }
    }
```

I am suspecting to manipulate the params, which is to add a statuscallback and statuscallbackevent, but I dont find any documentation on how should I modify the params...